# Ubuntu Studio: sddm greeter missing file - how to fix and how to switch sddm-greeter design

Tags: 22.04, do-release-upgrade, ubuntu-studio, sddm

I just upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 20.04 to 22.04.

When Ubuntu boots up the greeter screen seems very broken. No usernames appear, the background is grey and no text is displayed. Luckily I can still log in.
When checking syslog the following gets my attention:

"QML Image: Cannot open: file:///usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png"

When running sddm-greeter --test-mode --theme /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/
it gives some error but at least it looks like it is working visually.

**So my questions are:**

1. **How can I change the sddm-greeter background / design to breeze and**
2. **how can I fix the error "QML Image: Cannot open: file:///usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png"**

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

```
uname -a
Linux alex-studio-2004 5.15.0-46-lowlatency #49-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 4 18:56:09 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
ls /usr/share/sddm/themes/
breeze  ubuntustudio  ubuntu-theme
```

```
sddm-greeter --test-mode --theme /usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/
[10:01:02.366] (II) GREETER: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
[10:01:02.438] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
[10:01:02.438] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon2d.desktop"
[10:01:02.438] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/kodi.desktop"
[10:01:02.438] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
[10:01:02.439] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop"
[10:01:02.440] (II) GREETER: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme//theme.conf"
[10:01:02.445] (EE) GREETER: Socket error:  "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Invalid name"
[10:01:02.445] (WW) GREETER: QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
[10:01:02.511] (II) GREETER: Loading file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme//Main.qml...
[10:01:02.549] (WW) GREETER: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7fff364c96a0), parent's thread is QThread(0x5621b27410f0), current thread is QThread(0x5621b297f320)
[10:01:02.549] (WW) GREETER: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7fff364c96a0), parent's thread is QThread(0x5621b27410f0), current thread is QThread(0x5621b297f320)
[10:01:02.549] (WW) GREETER: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7fff364c96a0), parent's thread is QThread(0x5621b27410f0), current thread is QThread(0x5621b297f320)
[10:01:02.549] (WW) GREETER: QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
[10:01:02.787] (WW) GREETER: file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme//components/VirtualKeyboard.qml:11:1: Type InputPanel unavailable
[10:01:02.787] (WW) GREETER: qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/InputPanel.qml:127:5: Type Keyboard unavailable
[10:01:02.787] (WW) GREETER: qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/components/Keyboard.qml:38:1: module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Plugins" is not installed
[10:01:02.915] (WW) GREETER: file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme//Background.qml:21:5: QML Image: Cannot open: file:///usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png
[10:01:02.916] (II) GREETER: Adding view for "eDP-1-1" QRect(0,0 1920x1080)
[10:01:02.922] (WW) GREETER: file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:31:12: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
[10:01:02.923] (WW) GREETER: file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:31:12: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
```

```
sddm-greeter --test-mode --theme /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/
[10:01:46.599] (II) GREETER: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
[10:01:46.674] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
[10:01:46.674] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon2d.desktop"
[10:01:46.675] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/kodi.desktop"
[10:01:46.675] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
[10:01:46.675] (II) GREETER: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop"
[10:01:46.676] (II) GREETER: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze//theme.conf"
[10:01:46.680] (EE) GREETER: Socket error:  "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Invalid name"
[10:01:46.680] (WW) GREETER: QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
[10:01:46.744] (II) GREETER: Loading file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze//Main.qml...
[10:01:46.781] (WW) GREETER: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7fff87b37970), parent's thread is QThread(0x556ebe34d0f0), current thread is QThread(0x556ebe53d1a0)
[10:01:46.781] (WW) GREETER: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7fff87b37970), parent's thread is QThread(0x556ebe34d0f0), current thread is QThread(0x556ebe53d1a0)
[10:01:46.782] (WW) GREETER: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7fff87b37970), parent's thread is QThread(0x556ebe34d0f0), current thread is QThread(0x556ebe53d1a0)
[10:01:46.782] (WW) GREETER: QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
[10:01:47.009] (WW) GREETER: file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze//components/VirtualKeyboard.qml:11:1: Type InputPanel unavailable
[10:01:47.009] (WW) GREETER: qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/InputPanel.qml:127:5: Type Keyboard unavailable
[10:01:47.009] (WW) GREETER: qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/components/Keyboard.qml:38:1: module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Plugins" is not installed
[10:01:47.145] (II) GREETER: Adding view for "eDP-1-1" QRect(0,0 1920x1080)
[10:01:47.153] (WW) GREETER: file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:31:12: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
[10:01:47.154] (WW) GREETER: file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:31:12: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
```

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep sddm-greeter
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon2d.desktop"
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/kodi.desktop"
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop"
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/theme.conf"
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Connected to the daemon.
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
Aug 24 21:42:58 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Loading file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/Main.qml...
Aug 24 21:42:59 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffe913d1a10), parent's thread is QThread(0x557ccf3cc0f0), current thread is QThread(0x557ccf4b7070)
Aug 24 21:42:59 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffe913d1a10), parent's thread is QThread(0x557ccf3cc0f0), current thread is QThread(0x557ccf4b7070)
Aug 24 21:42:59 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffe913d1a10), parent's thread is QThread(0x557ccf3cc0f0), current thread is QThread(0x557ccf4b7070)
Aug 24 21:42:59 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
Aug 24 21:42:59 alex-studio-2004 dbus-daemon[999]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service' requested by ':1.46' (uid=137 pid=1885 comm="/usr/bin/sddm-greeter --socket /tmp/sddm-:0-rvPDBQ" label="unconfined")
Aug 24 21:43:00 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/Background.qml:21:5: QML Image: Cannot open: file:///usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png
Aug 24 21:43:00 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Adding view for "eDP-1-1" QRect(0,0 1920x1080)
Aug 24 21:43:00 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Message received from daemon: Capabilities
Aug 24 21:43:00 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Message received from daemon: HostName
Aug 24 21:43:05 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
Aug 24 21:43:05 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1885]: Message received from daemon: LoginSucceeded
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon2d.desktop"
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/kodi.desktop"
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop"
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/theme.conf"
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Connected to the daemon.
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Loading file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/Main.qml...
Aug 24 21:46:38 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffed59db520), parent's thread is QThread(0x55fc7e57a5e0), current thread is QThread(0x55fc7e653e60)
Aug 24 21:46:39 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: message repeated 2 times: [ QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffed59db520), parent's thread is QThread(0x55fc7e57a5e0), current thread is QThread(0x55fc7e653e60)]
Aug 24 21:46:39 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
Aug 24 21:46:39 alex-studio-2004 dbus-daemon[985]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service' requested by ':1.44' (uid=137 pid=1787 comm="/usr/bin/sddm-greeter --socket /tmp/sddm-:0-PVHiqR" label="unconfined")
Aug 24 21:46:39 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/Background.qml:21:5: QML Image: Cannot open: file:///usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png
Aug 24 21:46:39 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Adding view for "eDP-1-1" QRect(0,0 1920x1080)
Aug 24 21:46:40 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Message received from daemon: Capabilities
Aug 24 21:46:40 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Message received from daemon: HostName
Aug 24 21:46:50 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
Aug 24 21:46:50 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1787]: Message received from daemon: LoginSucceeded
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon2d.desktop"
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/kodi.desktop"
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop"
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/theme.conf"
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Connected to the daemon.
Aug 25 09:38:06 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
Aug 25 09:38:07 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Loading file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/Main.qml...
Aug 25 09:38:07 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffd71625420), parent's thread is QThread(0x55ac78a185e0), current thread is QThread(0x55ac78af24e0)
Aug 25 09:38:07 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: message repeated 2 times: [ QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffd71625420), parent's thread is QThread(0x55ac78a185e0), current thread is QThread(0x55ac78af24e0)]
Aug 25 09:38:07 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
Aug 25 09:38:07 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/Background.qml:21:5: QML Image: Cannot open: file:///usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png
Aug 25 09:38:07 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Adding view for "eDP-1-1" QRect(0,0 1920x1080)
Aug 25 09:38:08 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Message received from daemon: Capabilities
Aug 25 09:38:08 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Message received from daemon: HostName
Aug 25 09:38:22 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop"
Aug 25 09:38:23 alex-studio-2004 sddm-greeter[1806]: Message received from daemon: LoginSucceeded
```

```
ls -la /usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr 15 18:37 /usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png -> ubuntustudio_2204.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the release notes.  In it it clearly states

> **Upgrading to Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS**
>
> Note: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 only supported upgrades from 21.10, which
> has since reached end-of-life and upgrades from 21.10 may have already
> been shut-off by the time you read this. The following upgrade
> information is available for 20.04 LTS users for informational
> purposes only and may or may not work.
>
> Due to the change in desktop environment, direct upgrades to Ubuntu
> Studio 22.04 LTS from versions prior to 21.10 are unsupported.

https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/

*Problems should have been expected*

Comment: crap, didn't read this. but anyway, how to fix the greeter problem / change its design?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but it's posted *mainly* as I recall problems when Lubuntu switched from LXDE to LXQt (*and we created documentation that tried to walk through users around the issue; but issues varied on packages & user-changes*) and we had to treat the upgrade as *unsupported*.  Ubuntu Studio have followed the same steps, warning this was to occur in posts shortly after 20.04's release and the switch to KDE as default was announced.

Answer (score 0):

Did the same upgrade today. Seems like a missing package dependency to `ubuntustudio-wallpapers-jammy`

To install it manually

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-wallpapers-jammy
```

How I found out which package was missing

```
ls -l /usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 apr 15 18:37 /usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png -> ubuntustudio_2204.png
```

`ubuntustudio_2204.png` was missing

To find out which package it belongs to

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update

apt-file search /usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio_2204.png
ubuntustudio-wallpapers-jammy: /usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio_2204.png
```

Comment: it was a nice hint, but unfortunately it did not resolve my issue. `ubuntustudio-wallpapers-jammy` was in conflict with `ubuntustudio-wallpapers-focal`. So I had to uninstall the focal wallpaper before installing the jammy one. After reboot the issue is still the same. No changes at all.

Comment: Check if `/usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png` is pointing to `ubuntustudio_2204.png`

Comment: the file `/usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntustudio/ubuntustudio-default.png` is not available anymore. That is curious because regarding to my initial posting it was available and pointing to `ubuntustudio_2204.png`