# white screen on login pages after 22.04 update

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, login-screen, white-screen

I am experiencing an issue after update to 22.04 (UbuntuStudio with KDE Plasma): login (and lock) page are white, only the logo and text space are visible.

Everything is working fine, so not really a big deal, but I'd like to solve the issue.

I noticed something similar here (but the solution suggested there did not work for me):

[Deepin/Ubuntu white/black screen on login/lock pages (particularly with Deepin greeter)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140634/deepin-ubuntu-white-black-screen-on-login-lock-pages-particularly-with-deepin-g#_=)_

The problem occurs only at the login (initial or in case of opening/closing sessions) and not in case of unlock open session. This makes sense as it is related somehow to graphic drivers.

any tips?
thanks

Comment: i guess you have a similar problem as i do have https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425576/ubuntu-studio-sddm-greeter-missing-file-how-to-fix-and-how-to-switch-sddm-gre

Comment: yes! solved thanks.